# How can facebook application integrate with iPhone/Android application?

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

If I have made a Facebook Application with php, can I integrate it with iPhone/Android or cross platform application so that I don't need to build another server/database and native code?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. Maybe start with the [Android Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) or [iOS Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic web service for your php application if you need it to communicate with a native-code app on Android or iOS. You should consider making a mobile web app on Facebook if you don't want to write native code. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ for details on getting started.